# Strange characters appended at beginning of file in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Whenever I create a new file in Hadoop using Java, and write the contents, special characters are appended at the beginning of the file. Is there a way to eliminate? Below is the code

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
        String extractedXML = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\\r$", "");
        FSDataOutputStream fin = fs.create("/filelocation/input.txt");
        fin.writeUTF(extractedXML);
        fin.close();


$ hadoop fs -cat /filelocation/input.txt|head -5
)▒hello world
input1
hello again
hello
welcome again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, just by replacing the below lines

```
FSDataOutputStream fin = fs.create("/filelocation/input.txt");
fin.writeUTF(extractedXML);
fin.close();
```

with below code :

```
OutputStream os = fs.create( "/filelocation/input.txt",  new Progressable() {
    public void progress() {

    }
 });
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( os, "UTF-8" ) );
br.write(extractedXML);
br.close();
```